# Объединить ячейки в google sheet

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Есть два столбца. Нужно объединить (или соединить) ячейки во втором столбце, при условии что у них совпадают значения в первом.
Ссылка на пример: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u8ag-AYENdeo1rhnh4Iq5di0zQ4exJUi/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=110988137865799338833&rtpof=true&sd=true
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На выходе должно получиться так (первый столбец объединять не обязательно, главное второй)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если коды в столбце `А` расположены в неразрывных диапазонах (не перемешаны), можно быстро, без скриптов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Столбец `С`:

   `=ЕСЛИ(A2=A3;B2&СИМВОЛ(10)&C3;B2)`

Формула последовательно (снизу вверх) сцепляет значения для одинакового кода.

2. Столбец `D`:

   `=СЧЁТЕСЛИ($A$2:A2;A2)`

Накопительный счет одинаковых кодов. Здесь главное - единички (первая строка, в которой сцеплены все значения столбца `В` для одного кода из столбца `А`)

3. Фильтруем по столбцу `D` (оставляем единички)
4. Копируем диапазон данных.
5. Вставляем копированное на другой лист.
6. Столбцы `B`, D`` удаляем.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Супер! Как раз то что нужно. Я пытался сделать что-то подобное, но у меня не получилось